# how to make cupy run on nvidia graphics insted of intel integrated graphics

Tags: python, cupy

i am trying to make my code run on my GTX970m but instead it is running on my intel integrated graphics

i have tried

```
cp.cuda.Device(1).use()
```

since 0 is my intel graphics
but i got

```
cupy.cuda.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorInvalidDevice: invalid device ordinal
```

my computer is runnig windows 10 64bit and on the intel graphics my code executes perfectly(and slowly)

here is what my code is doing:
i have a 1000 by 1000 numpy matrix called phi
then i do this:

```py
def matrix_step_alt_gpu(phi):
    phiNPlus1 = phi.copy()
    phiNPlus1_c = (1 / (DX ** 2 + DY ** 2)) * ((DY ** 2 * cp.dot(LEFT, phi)) + (DX ** 2 * cp.dot(phi, LEFT)))
    phiNPlus1[1:-1, 1:-1] = phiNPlus1_c[1:-1, 1:-1]
    return phiNPlus1
```

and i repeat until this number(np.float64...) is maller the 10^-6:

```
np.float64(np.max(np.abs(phiNPlus1 - phi)) / PHI_0[0, 1])
```

just to remove any doubts i have also checked using my task manager's performance tab

nothing running:

[image: nothing running]

some code using cupy running:

[image]

Comment: you have an optimus laptop.  You may need to [set an optimus profile](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2615/~/how-do-i-customize-optimus-profiles-and-settings%3F) to get the NVIDIA GPU to be active during your python session.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set your `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` variable first:

[How do I select which GPU to run a job on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649102/how-do-i-select-which-gpu-to-run-a-job-on)

Hope the answer to that question helps.

Comment: i tried set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES that is what i found for windows but no luck also tried  
```  
 
import os os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"  
 
 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"  
```  
 
but it returns  
 
```  
 
cupy.cuda.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Answer (score 0):

CuPy won't run on Intel Integrated Graphics as it does not support CUDA.
Try using `nvidia-smi.exe` command instead of the task manager to see if your GPU is actually used.