# How to choose GPU when running phoronix-test-suite benchmark?

Tags: gpu, benchmarking

I am new to Phoronix Test Suite and ran my first test with `phoronix-test-suite benchmark testname`. This ran the test for one of my GPUs but not the other. How can I choose which GPU to use for the `benchmark`?

I've searched Google and skimmed the documentation for an answer but found nothing.

EDIT

The test I am trying to run is [here](https://openbenchmarking.org/result/2102179-HA-NVIDIAGEF76), using

```
phoronix-test-suite benchmark 2102179-HA-NVIDIAGEF76
```

I've also tried using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649102/how-do-i-select-which-gpu-to-run-a-job-on?) but to no avail.

I am using Phoronix Test Suite v10.2.2 (Harstad) on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

UPDATE

According to [this](https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite/issues/511) issue, phoronix-test-suite always chooses the default GPU on a given system.

> PTS currently sticks to using the default GPU configured by your system whether it be configured via PRIME handling or other multi-GPU setup configurations. Basically, it doesn't override your default GPU choice(s) or interfere beyond simply reporting the enumerated GPUs.

So the official way to change the GPU utilized by a phoronix benchmark is to change the 'default GPU' on the broader system. I don't understand what determines which GPU is the default or how to change the default. The above quote indicates that the default GPU might be changed using PRIME.

When running `nvidia-settings` the following message is printed.

> ** (nvidia-settings:9809): WARNING **: 15:46:41.950: PRIME: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/prime-supported” (No such file or directory)
> ** Message: 15:46:41.950: PRIME: is it supported? no

So it seems that whatever PRIME is, it's not part of my system.

Comment: To whoever voted to close the question, at least have the courtesy to leave a comment explaining why so I can improve the question or move it somewhere else if it doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: The close reason they chose (which I agree with) is that it's not about programming, it's about *using* existing software, and thus belongs on https://superuser.com/.

Comment: I've seen many similar questions on SO with up-votes and accepted answers. I'd think since it's such a simple question someone would just answer it and accept the 500+ reputation added to their account. But if it doesn't belong here then I guess it doesn't belong. Thanks.

Comment: Were the similar questions from more than 4 or 5 years ago?  In the early days of SO, before there were so many Stack Exchange sites and traffic volume was lower, SO was less picky.  This seems pretty clear-cut about using software (and probably a good fit for Superuser), and definitely not about programming or the performance of your own code.  IDK if you can get a moderator to refund your bounty or migrate with the bounty in tact, but losing it might be the cost of asking on the wrong site to start with.

Comment: Should I ask a question on superuser and then ask to move the bounty over, or should I just ask if a moderator can migrate the question and they will do the migration themselves?

Comment: You should google to see if there's any established precedent about migrating with bounties, either "definitely never, don't bother asking", or some procedure to follow (e.g. raising a flag on the question.)  I'd guess not, so next thing would be to ask a mod to refund the bounty here so you can delete the question.  You *could* ask on superuser while waiting to hear back, i.e. before you can delete this.  When you flag this question, let the mod know whether that you've already reposted so you don't need them to migrate, just refund the bounty.  Ask on meta if you're not sure.

Comment: looking at the [source](https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite/blob/master/pts-core/objects/phodevi/components/phodevi_gpu.php#L61) it seems to always use the first GPU it can find on `/sys/class/drm/card*/device/device`. So there's probably not much you can do apart raising an issue on [github](https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite/issues) and asking to implement the feature

Comment: As suggested, I raised an issue [here](https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite/issues/511).

Comment: can you try changing the default with the following method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/787030/setting-the-default-gpu ?

Comment: I followed the instructions but the only result was a black screen.

Comment: @timur I have to award the bounty today. Since the problem can't be reasonably solved, your comment pointing to the source code and the practical impossibility of selecting a GPU, in addition to the quote from the GitHub issue, should be the correct answer. Please post your comment as an answer and also link to the GitHub issue in your answer, and I'll award you the bounty for this question. Otherwise, I'll post an answer and accept it, and the bounty will vanish. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were looking to configure an Nvidia GPU, the logic is slightly different:
looking at the [source](https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite/blob/master/pts-core/objects/phodevi/components/phodevi_gpu.php#L51), PTS seems to always use the first GPU it can find on `nvidia-settings --query PCIID` output.
This theory has been further confirmed by PTS lead developer [on github](https://github.com/phoronix-test-suite/phoronix-test-suite/issues/511). So unfortunately there's no switch in PTS that would help achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you are using a Nividea GPU you can go to the Nividea control panel:

1. Go to Manage 3D settings
2. Go to "Program Settings"
3. Select your app (i.e in this case Phoronix-test-suite benchmark) and select the high-performance Nividea GPU.

Now run the benchmark test. <---- For Windows

for more help visit: https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/documentation/phoronix-test-suite.pdf

Comment: I apologize, I neglected to mention that I am not on Windows. I've updated the question to include system information.