# Run python code on specific gpu for lower python versions

Tags: python, tensorflow, environment-variables, gpu, virtual

I am trying to run a python code on a specific GPU on our server. The server has four GPUs. When I run the code using a virtual environment installed with python 3.8 and tensorflow 2.2, it works correctly on the specific GPU just by adding the below few lines at the first of the script.

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "2"  # run the code on a specified GPU
```

Many threads recommend use the above code to run python scripts on a specific GPU such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069883/how-to-set-specific-gpu-in-tensorflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649102/how-do-i-select-which-gpu-to-run-a-job-on).

However, When I tried to use the same way to run another python code on another virtual environment (with lower specifications) that was installed with python version 3.6.9 and tensorflow 1.12, it does not run on the GPU but on the CPU.

How can I run python code on a specific GPU in the case of the second virtual environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to define which GPUs are visible to the application. For example, if you want GPUs 0 and 2 visible, use `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,2`.

Comment: It does not work. Export gives another error that the "path" is not a valid identifier!

Comment: Can you paste the error here?

Comment: -bash: export: `algorithm/stack_predict.py': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `--load_model_dir=./results/stack_train_2022-01-14_18-46-46_467/': not a valid identifier

Comment: What is your full command you run when you encounter this error?

Comment: export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 0,1,2,3, python algorithm/stack_predict.py --load_model_dir=./results/stack_train

Comment: Did you install tensorflow 1.12 via `pip install tensorflow==1.12.0` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0`? Try latter, if you didn't use that.

Comment: Also, you should obviously run `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3` first, and then run your python file in a separate command.

Comment: I installed tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0  and ran the commands separately. But I got this error: ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Your CUDA version is not compatible with TF 1.12. See this table: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu to find the correct CUDA and NVIDIA driver version and install them.